# In excel, from a range of rows, return the column value of the row with the highest value from another column

Tags: excel, formula, spreadsheet

I apologize if the question sounds vague, but let me explain. I have a spreadsheet with 20 rows that each consist of a column for employee name, ID, Calls taken MTD, calls dropped MTD, and satisfaction rate respectively. I'm trying to create separate cells which will list the top 3 employees with the highest satisfaction rate. Since this spreadsheet is updated daily, I'm trying to create a formula which will list the top three for me as opposed to manually typing each time.

So basically instead of returning the cell containing the second highest value of satisfaction rate (which I did with =LARGE()), I am trying to return the name of the employee corresponding to that cell. That is where I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated. I'm just trying to do this in Excel only, not with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with LARGE, INDEX, AND MATCH (assuming you don't have two employees with the same rate)

`=index(employees,match(satisfaction_rate,satisfaction_rates,0))`

i.e.
`=index(employees,match(large(satisfaction_rates,2),satisfaction_rates,0))`